# Windows 10 verbose boot by modding bootmgfw.efi?

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, efi

Is it possible to verbose boot Windows 10 in UEFI mode via modifying the bootmgfw.efi file, or any other way? (I am using GRUB, not the default Windows bootloader, if that helps at all. I heard that GRUB2 doesn't have anything to do with it.)